# Quadratic equation in a graph

Tags: quadratics

The question is why does the line with equation ax+by+c=0 has a negative slop is wrong?
I get a and b<0 by -b/2a , is it correct to proof the values in this way? However, when I try to calculate its slope by -a/b, it is a negative slope. I have no idea why the above statement is wrong. Can anyone please teach me? Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdUY4.jpg)

Comment: `I get a and b<0 by -b/2a` Could you explain that step by step. Think you've got a sign wrong.

Comment: If you have a and b smaller than 0, when calculating slope by -a/b the slope will definitely be negative. This is my idea

Comment: Question was how did you get `a and b smaller than 0` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[$a<0$ because of downward parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function#Graph_of_the_univariate_function).
$\frac{-2b}{2a}>0 \implies b>0$ by the [$X$ co-ordinate of vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Coordinates_of_the_vertex). Now figure out the sign of slope of the straight line.
 P.S. : You don't actually need sign of $a$  to figure out the sign of slope.